# Sharepoint 2010 Create and Add Webpart Automatically In Sharepoint Site When Deploy WSP

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, wsp

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and I have developed webparts at visual studio 2010. I'm already using WSP to deploy my web application into server, but still should create and add the webpart manually through SharePoint site. Is there any way that we can deploy the application and automatically create and add all webparts into the site?

Answer (score 0):

Generally web parts are added to pages using features. Basically you create one site collection feature to deploy web part files to web part gallery and web scope feature which adds this web parts to pages (for example default site page).